# W10 duel boot Problems with kernel package in Ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS)

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, gpt

Lenovo ideapad 100-IBD

I hoping to inspire or get pointed in the right direction.

I am not able to make a comment and don't know how to get heard without 30 comment points. When your over 60 this all becomes blurred, so don't delete right away if I am in error.

"Every year" I try and fail at creating a ubuntu duel boot. Since UEFI vs Legacy AND MBR vs GPT etc.

My BRAND NEW Lenovo ideapad 100-IBD and win 10 and ubuntu are having a hard time to get together.

It seems that all the documentation about duel booting is before System bios has ENFORCED UEFI and GPT.

I have been going in circles for months; please message me if there is a solution for keeping my windows 10 and all its tiny partitions that keep (windows licences)
which I can not change the GPT because it will destroy the whole disk even the hidden "recover drive d:" that Lenovo has as as safeguard.

And Ubuntu won't install as Legacy when the drive/disk is in GPT format because it won't find the other OS; or the grub2 freezes.

This is happening with a new install, and I did understand grubs/autoexec 40 year ago; but not now.

I believe the only way that I can duel boot with my system is using a USB/another_external_drive that uses MBR?GPT if supported to boot into win 10 
or using a USB as the Ubuntu drive. I use windows to CNC mach4 and a virtual 
win10 won't work and/or is too complicated for me to make work.

However, I keep going in circles because I don't know how to keep win 10 happy with UEFI and GPT and also boot Ubuntu, because this is too complicated for someone that wants to use the internet without my own computer running my services and resources to fingerprint and create a voice, face, text and usage profile and using half of my monitor to promote ads etc.

I have considered; Changing the disk from GPT to MBR partition style without deleting data. However, I fear that win10 wouldn't work so I guess that isn't a solution for me because I need win10.

Maybe Ubuntu isn't my solution; "please message me" if there is a way to run win 10 and a popular linux that is still refusing to comply with this 
abuse of power; "waiver to class actions" etc.

Is my only real option to carry two computers around with me; one win and 
one that is Linux?

Sorry if I am not clear but all of this really is way more complicated than is used to be. Or maybe I need to format and install win7 and Ubuntu, that would work for me because my windows cnc software will run on win7 or win8.
There are way too many options; like booting, where should the grub2 be located when boot ubuntu on a usb pen drive that isn' a live-ubuntu.
I find it shocking that live-ubuntu always works, and that
the Ubuntu install either has a GPT, UEFI, GRUB2 or a Frozen blank purple screen issue. Why can the GRUB have an auto fix like the live-ubuntu 
does that is always there to fix issues or provide information about what
option are available? See what I mean, the questions are endless and the results for me has been very daunting and I am about to give up for the very
last time...

Comment: Ubuntu works well with UEFI and GPT, so the question is not clear. You don't need to delete any Windows partitions to install Ubuntu.

Comment: I have been trying to keep UEFI and GPT for win10 and 
keep Legacy version to avoid UEFI as I don't want to be fingerprinted nor profiled. If I am in error, please understand I am a 60 year old computer professional 40 years ago that is very uncomfortable with my devices having ID that are linked to a device that can watch and listen without me knowing. So the question, is really, what is a solution to avoid being linked UEFI and duel boot. 
I want to use Linux for everything, but need win10 for business cnc and to get things done that I can not get done with Linux. Thank you Pilot6.

Comment: The solution is to use Ubuntu with UEFI. I have no idea what you call "fingerprinted" and how it is related with UEFI. The question will be closed as too broad and unclear. It is not answerable.

Comment: Your right, people that don't know don't know what to ask, and don't deserve to be seen by people that may know what they are trying to accomplish.  But know, that a lot of people are not having success and that they posts are being removed so they won't every have success with linux.
I guess I am stuck between a rock and a hard place because Linux people don't respond kindly when ever they see someone mention windows. I get it, but this isn't the way to win. You just lost someone that really wanted to be here.

Comment: Linux people don't sell Linux, so we don't care if you use it or not ;-)

Comment: A forward thinking person would give away there OS for free and make it simple to get addicted to and install and use.

It is the best time for Linux to take advantage because a lot of windows users are not happy. The issue is that linux is not plug and play when it comes to installing. So your all really missing out on making more money than bill gate because there is opportunity for change.

Obviously, I am not going to get any help, and this is my last time trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98704/discussion-between-edoctoor-and-pilot6).